# Trying to convert 200 jpg files to an mp4 w/ ImageMagick. Receiving the same error over and over again

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert 200 .jpg files that were .ppm files into one .mp4 file.

In the same directory as the .jpg files, I ran this code:

```
convert -delay 6 -quality 95 test*ppm movie.mp4
```

and received this error message:

```
convert: no images defined `movie.mp4' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

What caused this error?

Comment: Do the images in the directory you are running the command from have a .jpg extension?

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg as a delegate in your ImageMagick install. MPEG formats require that ImageMagick have ffmpeg as a delegate library. You should see mpeg listed in Delegates section from `convert -version`. See the comment in the MPEG section of http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported

Answer (score 14):

Nevermind, I just ended up using ffmpeg. This is the code that I used:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

Comment: glob is defined in the POSIX standard and it's not available on Windows by default.

Comment: What does `-pattern_type glob` and `-c:v` do?

Answer (score 3):

From what I am reading the images you are running the command on have a .jpg extension.

Try

```
convert -delay 6 -quality 95 *.jpg movie.mp4
```

Comment: Sadly, I receive the error:  `convert: delegate failed \`"avconv" -v -1 -i "%M%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.`

Comment: `convert -delay 600 *.png movie.mp4` worked on my side (600 means 6 seconds)

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt install ffmpeg`

---

ImageMagick delegates video processing. I lost more than 5 hours to understand why such a bug NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Use `\ls` or `ls --color=never` to get **uncolored files list**

Failing command...

```
for f in $( ls *.JPG ); do convert -resize 1920x $f re_$f ; done
```

... becomes

```
for f in $( ls --color=never *.JPG ); do convert -resize 1920x $f re_$f ; done
```

---

**Details**

I got same error, due to colored output of `ls` command :

Error I got (in french):

```
$ for f in $( ls *.JPG ); do convert -resize 1920x $f re_$f ; done
convert: pas de délégué pour décoder ce format d'image `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: pas d'images définies `IMG_5235.JPG' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
convert: impossible d'ouvrir l'image `IMG_5236.JPG': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
```

Filenames are colored like in this screenshot :

[image]

My `ls` command is aliased to a `ls --color=auto` which leads convert file parameters to contain color sequences.

Disable `ls` colored output by using `\ls` :

```
for f in $( \ls *.JPG ); do convert -resize 1920x $f re_$f ; done
```

or :

```
for f in $( ls --color=never *.JPG ); do convert -resize 1920x $f re_$f ; done
```

Then convert may not give previous errors.
Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is:

```
convert src_file [options] dst_file
```

So in your case, it should be like:

```
convert movie.mp4 -delay 6 -quality 95 test*ppm movie_converted.mp4
```