# Error when creating TextClip with moviepy

Tags: python-2.7, imagemagick, moviepy

I'm trying create a textclip. But it's giving me this error:

```
>>> from moviepy.editor import *
>>> text = (TextClip("asdasda",color='white').set_pos((20,190)))

[MoviePy] This command returned an error !Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 1173, in __init__
raise IOError(error)
IOError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

convert: not authorized `@/tmp/tmpTs7EU5.txt' @ error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3405.
convert: no images defined `PNG32:/tmp/tmpy1f1J0.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.


This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect
```

The final line says I have not installed ImageMagick. But I already install with this command `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` and installed normally. I also installed `moviepy` normally via `pip install moviepy`. I also installed `pip install Wand`.

Comment: Did they all get installed completely with no errors? Is ImageMagick in your PATH environment variable or in a place that moviepy can find it? Do you have proper permission for /tmp and enough space?

Comment: Yes, was installed without errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to convert 200 jpg files to an mp4 w/ ImageMagick. Receiving the same error over and over again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779009/trying-to-convert-200-jpg-files-to-an-mp4-w-imagemagick-receiving-the-same-err)